# How to solve this sum of exponential integrals?

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, problem-solving

I have trouble solving this sum. I already rewrite it, but I don't know what to do next, also if it is even possible to solve it ?

Let:

$z = a + x i$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (E_{z}(i \pi n) + E_{z}(- i \pi n))$

Then:

$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (E_{z}(i \pi n) + E_{z}(- i \pi n)) = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
(
\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{- i \pi n t} t^{-z}dt + 
\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{i \pi n t} t^{-z}dt
) = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2 cos(\pi n t)}{t^z} dt)
=
2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{cos(\pi n t)}{t^z} dt)
$

And also can I write it as:

$
2 \int_1^\infty \frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty cos(\pi n t)}{t^z} dt
$

If not, then why ?

Comment: Exchange of limits isn't always possible. It holds in general when the double limit exists. It may hold when the double limit doesn't exist, but it also may not hold. Such cases have to be examined on a case-by-case basis. It obviously doesn't hold here, as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(\pi n t)$ is clearly divergent when $t$ is rational (probably for irrational $t$ as well, but that case isn't as clear). However, that doesn't mean that integrating first then summing will also diverge.

Comment: I found in wolfram documentation that this integral can be rewritten to definite integral, and it still looks like the summation is divergent.

[link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html)

The equation will look like this:

$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (E_{z}(i \pi n) + E_{z}(- i \pi n)) =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
(
\int_{0}^{1} e^{- i \pi n / t} t^{z-2}dt +
\int_{0}^{1} e^{i \pi n / t} t^{z-2}dt
) =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\int_{0}^{1} 2 cos(\pi n / t) t^{z-2} dt)
=
2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\int_{0}^{1} cos(\pi n / t) t^{z-2} dt)
$